# How to add haptics to Button in home screen widget (Glance API) in android

Tags: android, widget, jetpack, android-vibration, glance

I'm trying  to make a homescreen widget (simply a button) that cycles through two wallpapers i have, and I want to add haptic feedback to it.
I read the glance APIs have limited compose functionality so calling a function that triggers haptic feedback is not working in the below example. but I saw my Nothing phone's compass widget that gives haptic feedback when facing north, so I know it's at least possible. could you please guide me through this on how I can achieve this effect, kinda new to Android development.

```
// desktop widget to quickly toggle wallpaper
object WallChangeWidget : GlanceAppWidget() {
    val wallVariant = intPreferencesKey("wallVariant")
    override suspend fun provideGlance(context: Context, id: GlanceId) {
        provideContent {
            Button(text = "click", onClick = hapticsAndThenAction())
        }
    }

    @Composable
    fun hapticsAndThenAction(): Action {
        val haptic = LocalHapticFeedback.current
        haptic.performHapticFeedback(HapticFeedbackType.LongPress)
        return actionRunCallback(ChangeWallActionCallback::class.java)
    }
}
```

here's the ActionCallback that is triggered to swap the wallpapers

```
object ChangeWallActionCallback : ActionCallback {
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.R)
    override suspend fun onAction(
        context: Context,
        glanceId: GlanceId,
        parameters: ActionParameters
    ) {
        updateAppWidgetState(context, glanceId) { prefs ->
            val currentCount = prefs[WallChangeWidget.wallVariant]
            val x = WallpaperManager.getInstance(context)
            if (currentCount != 1) {
                val bmp: Bitmap =
                    BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/storage/emulated/0/Media/Pictures/WallSwitch/two.png")
                x.setBitmap(bmp)
                prefs[WallChangeWidget.wallVariant] = 1
            } else {

                val bmp: Bitmap =
                    BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/storage/emulated/0/Media/Pictures/WallSwitch/one.png")
                x.setBitmap(bmp)
//                x.clear()
                prefs[WallChangeWidget.wallVariant] = 0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the above code gives me the following exception, stating that of course this is not possible as LocalHapticFeedback is not present.

```
2024-03-23 21:56:31.511 32147-32183 WM-WorkerWrapper        com.sliya.np.ext.wallswitch          E  Work [ id=0f9eb632-47c1-4e38-bd06-86acbf66c988, tags={ androidx.glance.session.SessionWorker } ] failed because it threw an exception/error
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: CompositionLocal LocalHapticFeedback not present
at androidx.work.impl.utils.futures.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:516)
at androidx.work.impl.utils.futures.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:475)
at androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper$2.run(WorkerWrapper.java:311)
at androidx.work.impl.utils.SerialExecutor$Task.run(SerialExecutor.java:91)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: CompositionLocal LocalHapticFeedback not present
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.CompositionLocalsKt.noLocalProvidedFor(CompositionLocals.kt:220)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.CompositionLocalsKt.access$noLocalProvidedFor(CompositionLocals.kt:1)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.CompositionLocalsKt$LocalHapticFeedback$1.invoke(CompositionLocals.kt:117)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.CompositionLocalsKt$LocalHapticFeedback$1.invoke(CompositionLocals.kt:116)
at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
at androidx.compose.runtime.LazyValueHolder.getCurrent(ValueHolders.kt:29)
at androidx.compose.runtime.LazyValueHolder.getValue(ValueHolders.kt:31)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalMapKt.read(CompositionLocalMap.kt:88)
at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.consume(Composer.kt:2049)
at com.sliya.np.ext.wallswitch.WallChangeWidget.MyButton(WallChangeWidget.kt:90)
at com.sliya.np.ext.wallswitch.ComposableSingletons$WallChangeWidgetKt$lambda-1$1.invoke(WallChangeWidget.kt:34)
at com.sliya.np.ext.wallswitch.ComposableSingletons$WallChangeWidgetKt$lambda-1$1.invoke(WallChangeWidget.kt:33)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:108)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
at androidx.glance.appwidget.SizeBoxKt$SizeBox$1.invoke(SizeBox.kt:127)
at androidx.glance.appwidget.SizeBoxKt$SizeBox$1.invoke(SizeBox.kt:74)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:108)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
at androidx.glance.appwidget.SizeBoxKt.SizeBox-IbIYxLY(SizeBox.kt:74)
at androidx.glance.appwidget.SizeBoxKt.ForEachSize-eVKgIn8(SizeBox.kt:114)
at androidx.glance.appwidget.AppWidgetSession$provideGlance$1$1.invoke(AppWidgetSession.kt:110)
at androidx.glance.appwidget.AppWidgetSession$provideGlance$1$1.invoke(AppWidgetSession.kt:90)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:108)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
at androidx.glance.appwidget.AppWidgetSession$provideGlance$1.invoke(AppWidgetSession.kt:85)
at androidx.glance.appwidget.AppWidgetSession$provideGlance$1.invoke(AppWidgetSession.kt:84)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:108)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
at androidx.compose.runtime.RecomposeScopeImpl.compose(RecomposeScopeImpl.kt:169)
at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.recomposeToGroupEnd(Composer.kt:2468)
at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.skipCurrentGroup(Composer.kt:2737)
at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.doCompose(Composer.kt:3352)
at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.recompose$runtime_release(Composer.kt:3303)
2024-03-23 21:56:31.517 32147-32183 WM-WorkerWrapper        com.sliya.np.ext.wallswitch          E  at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.recompose(Composition.kt:781)
at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.performRecompose(Recomposer.kt:1097)
at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.access$performRecompose(Recomposer.kt:124)
at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer$runRecomposeAndApplyChanges$2$1.invoke(Recomposer.kt:569)
at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer$runRecomposeAndApplyChanges$2$1.invoke(Recomposer.kt:537)
at androidx.compose.runtime.BroadcastFrameClock$FrameAwaiter.resume(BroadcastFrameClock.kt:42)
at androidx.compose.runtime.BroadcastFrameClock.sendFrame(BroadcastFrameClock.kt:71)
at androidx.glance.session.InteractiveFrameClock.sendFrame(InteractiveFrameClock.kt:127)
at androidx.glance.session.InteractiveFrameClock.access$sendFrame(InteractiveFrameClock.kt:39)
at androidx.glance.session.InteractiveFrameClock$onNewAwaiters$2.invokeSuspend(InteractiveFrameClock.kt:117)
at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:232)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:334)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8293)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:578)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1053)
```

Comment: "I saw my Nothing phone's compass widget that gives haptic feedback when facing north" -- if that is a pre-installed bit of UI, then it might not actually *be* an app widget. I do not recall `RemoteViews` exposing any sort of haptics options, and Glance builds a `RemoteViews`.

Comment: @CommonsWare I just checked by installing 3rd party launcher (nova) and saw that compass widget was no longer present. so I assume it's not a standard widget. But then again it could also be vendor locking. Is there no other way for me to do haptics for home screen widgets? maybe through some sort of proxy service , invoking some function in main app's code etc.,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

deriving from @CommonsWave's answer calling `vibrate` from ActionCallback  worked.

```
object ChangeWallActionCallback : ActionCallback {
    override suspend fun onAction(
        context: Context,
        glanceId: GlanceId,
        parameters: ActionParameters
    ) {

     
        val vibrator = context.getSystemService(Vibrator::class.java)
        vibrator.vibrate(
            VibrationEffect.createPredefined(VibrationEffect.EFFECT_CLICK),
            VibrationAttributes.Builder().setUsage(VibrationAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION).build()
        )

// other stuff

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there no other way for me to do haptics for home screen widgets?

For anything that uses a `PendingIntent` to trigger logic in your app code, you could try to use the `Vibrator` system service to provide haptic feedback, perhaps in conjunction with [`VibrationEffect`](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/haptics/haptic-feedback#predefined_vibrationeffect). With Glance, `PendingIntent` is use for lambdas like your `onClick` one for your `Button`.

By eyeball, you could try:

```kotlin
    @Composable
    fun hapticsAndThenAction(): Action {
        val vibrator = context.getSystemService(Vibrator::class.java)

        // Requires VIBRATE permission
        vibrator.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createPredefined(VibrationEffect.EFFECT_HEAVY_CLICK))

        return actionRunCallback(ChangeWallActionCallback::class.java)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! had to make a few changes tho. Apparently the onClick function is computed only once (kinda obvious now, i only called it once) so, had to move your code in ActionCallback's onAction() and use vibrator there. and it worked as long as app was in foreground! just had to add VibrationAttributes.NOTIFICATION_USAGE for it to work in background, can i modify your answer before accepting this answer

Comment: @Boby: I do not think that you can edit my answer, but you can provide your own and accept your own answer. I am glad that you got this working!